# Android Unity3d limitation streamingAssetsPath only Start method (updated device/version or settings?)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

EDIT 02 April 2019.
With Jambla help I am now almost sure this is not a limitation or a bug of UnityWebRequest since now I know that the same code that I use in my project works for Jambla. Since the code is ok I think there are only two available solution:
1. The problem is the combination of Android version/device. I will try on another device as soon as I can.
2. There is a settings on my project in the build settings that prevent my game from copying files from streamingAssetsPath after Start method (I can confirm it's not after launch because if I try to enable a gameobject after launch and that object got a script that try to do a copy in the Start method it will still work).

If anyone know what setting is responsible for this behaviour please answer this question. If you experience the same behaviour on a version of android and/or a device please tell me what device/version.

ORIGINAL QUESTION.
I know that, to read from the streamingAssetsPath on Android, I need to use UnityWebRequest Get from the streamingAssetsPath and yield return unitywebrequest.SendWebRequest() in a Coroutine.
I also check if the platform is Android because on PC I don't need to use UnityWebRequest.
Usually I copy a json file from the streamingAssetsPath to the persistentDataPath and work from there (since I can create and modify files on PC and Android/iOS on persistentDataPath).
My problem is that the reading only works on the Start method (or a Coroutine on the Start method). I don't know why but when I try to read files from the streamingAssetsPath at runtime on android (for example in the Update or in a method called from a button) I'm not able to do that.
I would like to know if this is an Android/Unity limitation or if I can solve it.

My code is something like this (this code is only for the Android part):

```
string fileUrlPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "myjsonfile.json");
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(fileUrlPath);
yield return www.SendWebRequest(); //this is where the Coroutine fail if not on Start method
```

after that I usually use a File.WriteAllBytes to copy my json to the persistentDataPath.

Once I know if this is a limitation I will be able to continue anyway (I can workaround this by copying the file on the Start method after all... The main problem was to know about that), but if I can do it by doing something I don't know I would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am implementing a similar method in my application and I am able to read from the streamingAssetsPath during runtime.

Here is my implementation:

```
private void LoadGameData()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    string filePath = Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, gameDataFileName);

        if (File.Exists (filePath)) {
            string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText (filePath);
            GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData> (dataAsJson);
            allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
        } else 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Cannot load game data!");
        }
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/data.json";
        WWW www = new WWW(path); 
        while(!www.isDone){}
        string dataAsJson1 = www.text;
        GameData loadedData1 = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData> (dataAsJson1);
        allRoundData = loadedData1.allRoundData;
    #endif
}
```

Here is another implementation that works on both Android and in the Editor:

```
private void LoadGameData()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetText());
}

IEnumerator GetText()
{
    string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/data.json";
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(path);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    Debug.Log("Loaded Q's");
    string dataAsJson1 = www.downloadHandler.text;
    GameData loadedData1 = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(dataAsJson1);
    allRoundData = loadedData1.allRoundData;

}
```

Comment: thank you but you should note that WWW Class is Obsolete https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html I asked to the unity3d team and it will be removed in the future so pay attention. Still maybe it's a current limitation of the UnityWebRequest class, after all some version ago it was not possible to do some of the things that I'm able to do right now (so it was not possible to use it instead of WWW class).

Comment: Anyway I will try to ask to the Unity3d team if this is a bug/limitation of UnityWebRequest

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working version that uses UnityWebRequest. I have tested this in the editor and on Android and it works.

Comment: I used the same code (I tried with both Path Combine and string + string)... but in my device (xperia z5 compact android version 7.1.1) the yield return www.SendWebRequest(); only works if I call GetText or LoadGameData in the Start method. If your code does work on android maybe it's a limitation of the android device/version that I use... or something in the settings build. I'm sure it is not the code since I use the same code.

Comment: In the end I decided to accept your post, at least thanks to your answer I know that it's not a problem with my code.